# How do I read a double from file?

Tags: c++, file, c++11

I came up with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
  std::ifstream a0;
  a0.open("data/a0", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
  double d;
  a0 >> d;
  printf("%e\n", d);
}
```

I compile with

```
g++ -s -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++0x -o program program.cpp
```

But it doesn't work - it prints 0 (the actual first 8 bytes of the file are `3D 8F A0 BB  E0 00 00 00`).
What is more interesting, is that when the `data/a0` file doesn't exist, garbage is output, but if the file does exist, the output is always strictly 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file is binary, you must use *unformatted* input functions with it:

```
double d;
if (!a0.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&d), sizeof(d))) {
  // error occurred
}
std::cout << d << '\n';
```

Operator `>>` does *formatted* input, which means it expects *text* in the file.

**EDIT**

Sorry, originally used `get()` instead of `read()`, which is more useful for reading text files in binary format.

Comment: I must have been blind :( Thanks! Is there a simple way to make this read the double in big-endian order?

Comment: @Rogach I'm afraid there isn't. You have to read it into memory (perhaps into a `unsigned char[sizeof(double)]` or `std::arrray<unsigned char, sizeof(double)>`) and convert it yourself.

Comment: Hm. It will be easier for me to write that file in little-endian as well, so I won't need converting. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the file format is actually binary?

If you can view the file in a text editor then drop the ios::binary flag.

Also try %g as the printf format instead; it's the normal one for displaying a double.

Comment: `%e` is perfectly fine for `double`, it means exponential notation. `%f` means fixed notation, and `%g` means "use the one more appropriate for the double's particular value."